# Why wasm binary code is empty when I create a raw pointer at compile time and use it in a buffer?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I'm trying to build `no_std` code with `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn test() {
    let mut idx: i32 = 10;
    let ptr = &mut idx as *mut i32;

    let buffer = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, 10) };

    for pixel in buffer.iter_mut() {
        *pixel = 0x7d2b7500;
    }
}
```

After the build, I get the following wasm binary code (I use `wasm2wat` tool):

```
(module
  (type (;0;) (func))
  (func (;0;) (type 0)
    nop)
  (memory (;0;) 16)
  (global (;0;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (global (;1;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (export "memory" (memory 0))
  (export "test" (func 0))
  (export "__data_end" (global 0))
  (export "__heap_base" (global 1)))
```

My `test` function is empty for some reason ("nop").

But when I pass a raw pointer `ptr` from outside as `test` function argument:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn test(ptr: *mut i32) {
    let buffer = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, 10) };

    for pixel in buffer.iter_mut() {
    *pixel = 0x7d2b7500;
    }
}
```

wasm code generates:

```
(module
(type (;0;) (func (param i32)))
  (func (;0;) (type 0) (param i32)
    local.get 0
    i64.const 9019431323700000000
    i64.store offset=32 align=4
    local.get 0
    i64.const 9019431323700000000
    i64.store offset=24 align=4
    local.get 0
    i64.const 9019431323700000000
    i64.store offset=16 align=4
    local.get 0
    i64.const 9019431323700000000
    i64.store offset=8 align=4
    local.get 0
    i64.const 9019431323700000000
    i64.store align=4)
  (memory (;0;) 16)
  (global (;0;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (global (;1;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (export "memory" (memory 0))
  (export "test" (func 0))
  (export "__data_end" (global 0))
  (export "__heap_base" (global 1)))
```

Why it happens?

I'm expecting wasm generated code

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but it's worth a shot: what you are doing is **completely** UB. Maybe Rust is "smart" enough to understand reaching `test` is UB, so it can "optimize" it away. This may seem weird, but as soon as you reach UB, you don't have any more guarantees, including the compiler producing sensible code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just modifying local stack memory without returning the value,  so it has no side effects and can be optimized out. You could potentially use [write_volatile](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write_volatile.html) to stop this.

Your code is also UB because you are not meeting the safety requirements in the documentation for [from_raw_parts_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts_mut.html). In particular

```
data must point to len consecutive properly initialized values of type T.
```

Comment: Putting it the other way: your code is UB so it has no sensible evaluation at all, nop being a valid outcome. Also, your code doesn't have side-effects. One of the reasons is making the compiler optimize out your writes, but you should only care about the first (and you should care about the first).